# What time zone is used on the Xur (Agent of the Nine) timetable?

Tags: destiny

I found [this timetable](http://destinynews.net/xur-agent-nine/) for when Xur is said to appear, but only the GMT time zone is shown.

Seeing as I'm living in Australia, the time zone is often radically different to everywhere else in the world. So what time zone is used/what time does Xur appear in AEST?

Comment: UTC, same as Stack Exchange.

Comment: Above that timetable there is: "This vendor is not always available, below is a schedule of upcoming dates & times (GMT) when you can find Agent of the Nine in-game:". Doesn't that mean it is in GMT, or do I miss something?

Comment: @Mathias711 Whoops! Missed that.

Comment: I had no idea that Australia had it's very own time zone! That's amazing.

Comment: GMT and UTC are the same thing (assuming correct usage). It is important to note that this is not the same as UK time though since we have BST in the summer which is GMT+1.

Comment: Although this question is over a year old now, there are apps  on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crocusgames.whereisxur&hl=en) and the [Apple Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/where-is-xur-for-destiny/id955286784?mt=8) that work well for this. They will notify you when he arrives, tell you where he is and what he is seliing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AEST (Australian Eastern Standard Time) is +10 hours ahead of UTC/GMT (Coordinated Universal Time/Greenwich Mean Time).

When Xur arrives in the Tower, he arrives between the hours of 9am Friday and 9am Sunday UTC, in random locations.

Converted to AEST, this timetable is 7pm Friday (arrival) and 7pm Sunday (departure). *Xur will only appear on the map/in the Destiny app between these hours*.

Comment: Its worth noting that this the arrival time is the same time as bounties reset and I think all daily things reset.

Answer (score 1):

UTC, [same as Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). AEST is UTC+10, so add ten hours to the time on the chart to get your local time.

Comment: You know, I thought he meant EST as in UTC-5, but then I checked his profile >_>

Comment: @Unionhawk So used to just calling it "EST" over here lol. But I did add "I'm living in Australia"...